# Spring framework with Hibernate DAO as singleton

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, memory-leaks

I have a problem with Spring + Hibernate. I am using Hibernate, and I would like to create the DAOs via Spring. I have edited the spring.xml, now it looks like this.

```
<property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.mytest.entityClass</value>
        </list>
    </property>
```

and the DAO addition looks like this:

```
<bean id="myDAOClass" class="com.myclasses.MyDAOClassImpl" scope="singleton">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Please note, that the 'singleton' is set as a scope for the DAO object. However, the DAO class will be instantiated every single time that the session starts, and it will be created multiple times. This behaviour is strange enough, but after the session is invalidated, the singleton objects wont be destroyed and this leads to a serious memory leak issue. Could you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Spring beans are singleton by default so `scope="singleton"` is redundant.

Comment: The Spring beans are singleton per application context so should be started with each context you create in the Spring container.  When you say 'session' what are you referring to?

Comment: @Lee Okay, I am really confused right now. If the default scope is singleton, why can I see bunch of instances in the Profiler? :(

Comment: @Lee By session I mean HTTP session, standard login, do something, logout procedure.

Comment: @Lee I am using the following snippet in ViewScoped EJBs:

private ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring4.xml");

These beans are instantiated serveral times, maybe this is the problem?

Comment: Yes, you are programatically creating multiple Application Contexts - review the Spring docs for how to do this properly as it's very specific to the version of Spring you are using.

Comment: @NathanHughes Okay, could you show me an example how should I handle this? I have seen this solution in an example, and I thought it would be good for my project.

Comment: @Lee Okay, thank you very much. :)